# Why does the program print the height value 0 instead of the one I set?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, output

I am confused about how are the methods and constructors called at runtime, since the derived constructor is printed 3 times and the height is printed 0

I have tried printing some messages inside methods and constructors as to know what exactly is happening

```
public class Derived extends Base{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Derived d = new Derived();
    }

    protected Derived(){
        System.out.println("Inside Derived Const");
        showAll();
    }

    protected void showAll(){
        System.out.println("Inside Derived showAll");
        System.out.println(getClass().getName()+" : "+height);
    }

    double height = 106.0;
}

class Base{

    protected Base(){
        System.out.println("Inside Base Const");
        showAll();
    }

    protected void showAll(){
        System.out.println("Inside Base showAll");
        System.out.println(getClass().getName()+" : "+height);
    }

    double height = 196.0;
}
```

I expected the output to be

```
Hello world
Derived : 106
Base : 196
```

instead I am getting

```
Hello World
Inside Base Const
Inside Derived showAll
Derived : 0.0
Inside Derived Const
Inside Derived showAll
Derived : 106.0
```

Comment: add height to the method as a parameter and just pass the value when you call the method. so like showAll(double height){ System.out.println("height: "  + height }

Comment: main function should not be inside the class

Comment: I came across this question in an interview, so the question was to predict the output and thats why I am trying to figure out the reason of the output
@TymekWojnarowski the program doesn't give any error,

Comment: The object has not been fully instantiated when you are trying to print out the value of `Derived::height`

Comment: `showAll` is overriden by derived class, so it is called (also from `Base`). When `Base` is calling `showAll` inside its constructor, which is part of derived construction, that latter is not yet finished, that is, the derived calss it not fully constructed

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski why not? just a design matter and would have no impact on given *problem*

Comment: instance initializers will execute after object is initialized(i.e after constructor invokation) Hope this will be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: You can refer to the below change that i did to understand the runtime of your code and explanation.Feel free to comment if you want more clarifications. @struct_dhancha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you derived the `Derived` class from `Base` class and shadowing the variable and also overriding the methods.

You're calling the constructor of the Base class whenever you're instantiating the Derived class with:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
```

Here what happens when you're calling the above code:

- Constructor of Base class `Base()` is called,
- then `"Inside Base Const"` is printed,
- method `showAll()` is not called because it's being override. Method `showAll()` inside the `Derived` class is called instead,
- `"Inside Base showAll"` is printed,
- `"Derived : 106.0"` is printed because `double height = 196.0;` inside Base class is being shadowed by `double height = 106.0;` inside the `Derived` class.

Comment: And "Derived: 0.0" is shown because the height (in Derived) hasn't been initialized yet when showAll is called from the Base constructor

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Shaddowing of member variables is inapplicable to the question.  "Derived : 106.0" is printed by the `showAll()` method of the **base** class, because `getClass().getName()` will return "Derived"  even if it is invoked from within a method of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled upon a major deficiency in the workings of java (and other object-oriented languages.)  This deficiency is allowed by the compiler, but any decent IDE will detect it and show you a warning, so the fact that you are posting this question tells me that you are compiling without some very important warnings enabled.  Go enable as many warnings as you can on your IDE, and your IDE will point the problem out to you.  But I will now explain it anyway.

In the constructor of your base class, you are invoking `showAll()`.  This is a non-final method, so any derived class may override it.

**It is a grave mistake to invoke an overridable method from within a constructor**.

You see, at the moment that the base class constructor is being invoked, the derived class constructor has not been invoked yet, and the object has not been fully initialized.  So, what is simply happening is that at the moment that your base class constructor is running, your statement `double height = 106.0;` of your derived class has not been executed yet.  That's why the `height` member of your derived class appears to contain zero.  Zero is simply the default, and `106.0` has not been stored in it yet.

If you enable the right warnings in your IDE, then your IDE will warn you about any invocations of non-final methods from within a constructor.  (In my opinion, this should not be a warning, it should be an error.)

So, let me briefly address each of your expectations vs. results:

You expected the following:

```
Hello world
Derived : 106
Base : 196
```

That's wrong. If you had no other mistakes, you should have expected the following:

```
Hello world
Base : 196
Derived : 106
```

That's because your `Derived` constructor starts with an implicit (hidden) call to the `Base` constructor, so the base constructor will always be invoked first.  This is evident by your `System.out.println("Inside X Const")` statements.

But instead you got the following:

```
Hello World
Derived : 0.0
Derived : 106.0
```

Both lines appear to come from the 'Derived' class, because `getClass()` will return the class of the current object, and you have only created one object, which is an instance of `Derived`.  So, `getClass()` will return `Derived` when invoked from within the `Derived` class, and it will also return `Derived` when invoked from within the `Base` class.

And then the `0.0` as I have already explained comes from the uninitialized member variable of the `Derived` instance, since you are invoking the `showAll()` overridable from within the constructor of the base class, so the derived class has not had a chance to initialize itself at the moment that the method is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but this was just a question which i came across in an interview and I was running this code on sublime text and windows powershell

Answer (score 0):

An important point to note is, when subclass object is created, a separate object of super class object will not be created.

Only a subclass object is created that has super class variables.

so we unable to blindly say that whenever a class constructor is executed, object of that class is created or not. Please refer to below changes and see.

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.getClass();
    }

    protected Derived() {
        System.out.println("Inside Derived Const");
        System.out.println("Sub class object hashcode :" + this.hashCode());
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
        showAll();
    }

    protected void showAll() {
        System.out.println("Inside Derived showAll");
        System.out.println("Sub class object hashcode :" + this.hashCode());
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " : " + height);
    }

    double height = 106.0;
}

class Base {

    protected Base() {
        System.out.println("Inside Base Const");
        System.out.println("Super class object hashcode :" + this.hashCode());
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
        showAll();
    }

    protected void showAll() {
        System.out.println("Inside Base showAll");
        System.out.println("Sub class object hashcode :" + this.hashCode());
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " : " + height);
    }

    double height = 196.0;
}
```

Output

```
Hello World
Inside Base Const
Super class object hashcode :1917513796
Derived
Inside Derived showAll
Sub class object hashcode :1917513796
Derived : 0.0
Inside Derived Const
Sub class object hashcode :1917513796
Derived
Inside Derived showAll
Sub class object hashcode :1917513796
Derived : 106.0
```

- As we can observe that both super class(Base) object hashcode and
  subclass(Derived) object hashcode are same, so only one object is
  created.
- This object is of class Derived as when we try to print name of class
  which object is created, it is printing "Derived" which is subclass.
- When you have called showAll() in super class for first time it
  doesn't have a value for height variable because of the method
  showAll has overridden.But the value has not assigned at that line it calls.
- When the method showAll() has called inside the subclass it has the
  value assigned which is 196.0. This is due to variable hiding*.

(**Variable hiding:** When the child and parent classes both have a variable with the same name, the child class' variable hides the parent class' variable.)